# SQL query where column has characters other than numbers or commas or spaces

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'v tried PATINDEX and dabbled in RegEx's, but all I want to do is query rows where a particular column has characters other than numbers, commas, or spaces.

These are all fine:

```
740
79783
00830,01512
77727
52256, 52264, 00122
```

But I want to find anything else. Stuff like:

```
N/A
TBA
101A
12345.11111
```

Can one RegEx do this, do I group PATINDEX's? I don't know where to start!

Comment: How do TBA and 101A fit into the other characters case?

Comment: TBA and 101A are nothing but letters and numbers. Where do you see them being equivalent to N/A and 12345.11111 which have a slash and a dot in them?

Comment: They're just examples. They're things that I imagine users entering in their data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TSQL has limited support for regular expression. Below works if you know list of invalid characters like alphabets , decimal operator BEFORE.

```
select * from sample 
where val NOT like '%[a-zA-Z.]%'
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/18106/6)

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle too!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this works on your version, but try:

```
WHERE (particular_column REGEXP '[^0-9\s,]')
```

Comment: This regex will work using `LIKE` in SQL Server, but if OP wants an output like 'TBA' which is nothing but letters, then it won't.

Comment: REGEXP is not availaible for SQL Server , its a MySQL operator